# Magento: How to get Order shipping address line 2

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to get a second line of Magento order shipping address, currently I am getting information like so:

```
        $this->formatText($order->getBillingAddress()->getData('prefix')),
        $this->formatText($order->getBillingAddress()->getData('firstname')),
        $this->formatText($order->getBillingAddress()->getData('middlename')),
        $this->formatText($order->getBillingAddress()->getData('lastname')),
        $this->formatText($order->getBillingAddress()->getData('suffix')),
        $this->formatText($order->getBillingAddress()->getData('street')),
        $this->formatText($order->getBillingAddress()->getData('city')),
        $this->formatText($order->getBillingAddress()->getData('region')),
        $this->formatText($order->getBillingAddress()->getData('country_id')),
```

All is good, however when customer supplies address line 2, see image below:

[image]

My code does not capture that line, anyone knows how to get address line 2 in Magento?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the street line like below :

```
$order->getBillingAddress()->getStreet(1);
$order->getBillingAddress()->getStreet(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Tried repairing it through proper configuration?

```
System Config -> Customers -> Customer Configuration -> Name and Address Options
```

Change **Number of Lines in a Street Address**

Unless your template is bolloxed up, it checks this config to know how many address lines to include in the templates and database.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @Khushbu_sipl, in my configuration, I have set up Magento to record 2 lines. And thanks to Manashvi birla answer above, I am now able to retrieve the second line. All good :)

Comment: okay :) good luck